# URL rewriting without changing URL .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I want to rewrite my URL

**From:**

```
https://example.com/fr/transporter/transporterPublicProfile.php?profil=1927
```

**To:**

```
https://example.com/fr/profil-des-transporteurs/1927
```

**When ever a user visit this URL:**

```
https://example.com/fr/transporter/transporterPublicProfile.php?profil=1927
```

**It should appear like this:**

```
https://example.com/fr/profil-des-transporteurs/1927
```

**And if a user visit this URL:**

```
https://example.com/fr/profil-des-transporteurs/1927
```

Its should remain as it is.

**What I have tried so far is:**

```
RewriteRule ^profil-des-transporteurs/(.*)$ /fr/transporter/profil.php?oid=$1 [L]
```

It changes the URL as I want but the problem is that, the links on that page doesn't works properly. The page is using relative paths for images etc w.r.t new URL i.e:

```
https://example.com/fr/profil-des-transporteurs/
```

Comment: Put `[R=301,L]` at the end.

Comment: It changes the URL and also redirects completely to the new URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+fr/transporter/transporterPublicProfile\.php\?profil=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ fr/profil-des-transporteurs/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^fr/profil-des-transporteurs/([^/.]+)/?$ fr/transporter/transporterPublicProfile.php?profile=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Then for resolving relative links used for images/js/css paths you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/fr/transporter/" />
```

Comment: why on DOCUMENT_ROOT can i place the htaccess file on subdirectory 'fr' folder ?

Comment: please tell me what kind of adjusting  required in above htaccess rules if real directory is fr ? I want to place my htaccess file in subdirectory 'fr' .

Comment: I cannot modify this answer as a comments response, better you create a new question so that I can post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a base tag in your html, so all paths will be relative to it

```
<base href="https://example.com/fr/transporter/">
```

Comment: For more information, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag) should prove useful

Comment: After adding Base Tag, I tried this URL:
https://example.com/fr/profil-des-transporteurs/1927

It appeared like this:
https://example.com/fr/transporter/transporterPublicProfile.php

It actually solved my images path problem but the URL was the same as original